# How to share my android code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been working on an Android app for a company and now I have to pass it off to another software engineer.  How do I pass on everything via email? is there something I can do to export everything in eclipse so someone can continue where I left off?

Comment: This question does not comply with SO guidelines...

Comment: @shoerat:  I'm not so sure I agree...despite the question needing a *little* more work, it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @shoerat - untrue, there's nothing wrong with it.  Counting the tags, it's specific enough to answer.

Comment: Well, my bad then. I was in an impression that "How do I email source code?" was not good enough question to put in SO.

Comment: That is not the question that was asked though.  There's more than source code - there's also project configuration (typically out of tree for Eclipse), which while it can be re-generated, is desirable to preserve if possible.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you're not using a version control system.

Go get one now. Run - Don't walk.

Get the company to invest a couple of bucks in a private Github account or something similar. Get your code into the version control system, and then send your replacement the credentials to log into the version control system.

Comment: www.github.com,
You should use version control system :d

Comment: +1 for, Run - Don't Walk.

Comment: +1 First idea comes in my mind is Github. Nice answer

Answer (score 4):

To perform a one-time move of your project, right-click the project, select `Export` and select `Archive file` under the `General` node. You can attach that archive file to an email and pass it on; the other developer can simply import this Eclipse project archive.

For continuous code-sharing use version control, such as git, on a shared repository. [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.com) offers free service, even for closed-source projects, and there are other providers out there. Version control has the added benefit of allowing you tagging, branching, etc... it's really the only practical way to develop and deploy well-used apps.

Comment: +1 for answering the question that was actually asked, *before* moving on to giving alternative advice.  A VCS is a great thing for ongoing development, but not always the answer for a one-time "toss over the wall" especially if teams have, er, philosophical differences.

Answer (score -1):

go to you workspace folder. find your application folder. 
attach it to .RAR and send this RAR to the other guy. the other guy will have to import the application via eclipse just by "Importing an existence application"

### P.S:  email clients such as GMAIL has some security issues with some extensions, that's why i mentioned to use .RAR extension. i'm trying to be simple as such.

Comment: RAR?  Really?  Why not use a good, robust version control system?

Comment: @Makto - perhaps because a version control system does not, by itself, meet the request to "pass on everything via email".

Comment: @Makoto i said RAR as this will be simplest way to send his code over an email as some email clients such as GMAIL has some security issues with some extensions . and lol i'm getting aloot of down voting. for being simple .